# Windows - programmatically release memory

Tags: c#, windows, memory, memory-management, ram

There is Sysinternals "RAMMap" app. It has ability to show usage and release some types of memory. Does anyone know how to release the memory programmatically as the RAMMap does? I don't want apps or services of that kind, I'm asking for a in code solution (best .NET/C#).

Comment: Are you focused on releasing memory in *your* program or doing this for other programs running on the same computer?

Comment: Yes, in my program for whole system - as RAMMap does that.

Comment: Per the "RAMMap" web site it looks like they are using windows internals to accomplish this. You might consider getting a book or looking up some details about this. See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901.aspx

Comment: I've seen this page earlier. This would be what I need, but I'm asking if someone already done similar thing.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? RAMMap will primarily be aimed at unmanaged applications, but you want this for .NET, which is different.

Comment: .NET is not obligatory, I need the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually reduce your .NET's app's working set by using the [Process.MaxWorkingSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.maxworkingset) property.

This is what Windows will do anyway when the system runs low on memory or when you minimise your app to the task bar. But controlling when this happens lets you strip your app's working set to its minimum size for investigation purposes.